# Laravel 5 user role check before

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have some trouble figuring out how to do this properly.
I have **Users** that can create **Articles** which can be `viewed`, `edited` and `deleted`. I want to restrict the edit and delete actions if the currently logged in user is not the creator of the Article.
I have already done this using Policies and use Gate within a Form Request, but if i understand correctly FormRequest is only for POST requests. And I currently pass the FormRequest as a parameter to the getEdit() action. That seems wrong.

So how can I make sure the user can neither access nor edit the Article?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using Form Requests for GET requests.

Comment: using Middleware would be a good choice. Create a middleware and check user role there. Process all those routes through Middleware.

Answer (score 0):

If you already defined a Policy you can directly access it using the `Gate` facade within your controller action like this:

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
    $reference = Reference::findOrFail($id);

    if (Gate::denies('owns-reference', $reference))
        abort(403);

    return view('reference.edit')
           ->with('reference', $reference);
}
```

Just make sure to include the `Gate` on top of your file like this:

`use Gate;`

Comment: Yeah i'd like to not have this king of logic in my controller if that is possible

Comment: Can I do something similar with a middleware?

Comment: because i have to write the same code twice (in getEdit() and postEdit())

Comment: I wouldn't use a middleware. Since you have probably different roles for different models it would require a different middleware each time.
As Thomas Kim pointed out in his comment on your question: There is nothing wrong using the Request class in a get request. Look at this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#within-form-requests